# How to remove parameters from stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters, firebird

I am using firebird database 2.5 which has a stored procedure. When I run it, it asks me for three parameters (FITEMNO, FDATE from and TDATE). After giving parameters, it shows relevant data/grid. I want to remove these parameters from the stored procedure so that I can see all data. Here is the procedure

```
    declare variable FID Integer;
     declare variable ExistITem Integer;
     declare variable FSIID Integer;
begin
ITEMNO=FITEMNO;
  for select D.ARInvoiceID, D.Seq,
    D.ITEMRESERVED1, D.ITEMRESERVED2, D.ITEMRESERVED3, D.ITEMRESERVED4, D.ITEMRESERVED5,
    D.ITEMRESERVED6, D.ITEMRESERVED7, D.ITEMRESERVED8, D.ITEMRESERVED9, D.ITEMRESERVED10, D.WAREHOUSEID,
    D.QUANTITY, D.DEPTID, D.PROJECTID, D.BRUTOUNITPRICE, D.ITEMUNIT, D.TAXCODES, D.ITEMDISCPC, D.QTYCONTROL, D.ITEMOVDESC,
    D.DOID, D.DOSEQ, D.SOID, D.SOSEQ
    from ARINVDET D inner join ARINV M on M.ARINVOICEID=D.ARINVOICEID
    where D.ITEMNO=:ITEMNO and M.DeliveryOrder=0 and InvoiceDate between :FDate and :TDate --and GroupSeq+0 is null
      into :FID, :SEQ, :ITEMRESERVED1, :ITEMRESERVED2, :ITEMRESERVED3, :ITEMRESERVED4, :ITEMRESERVED5,
    :ITEMRESERVED6, :ITEMRESERVED7, :ITEMRESERVED8, :ITEMRESERVED9, :ITEMRESERVED10, :WAREHOUSEID,
    :INVQTY, :DEPTID, :PROJECTID, :UNITPRICE, :ITEMUNIT, :TAXCODES, :ITEMDISCPC, :QTYCONTROL, :ITEMOVDESC,
    :DOID, :DOSEQ, :SOID, :SOSEQ do begin
    select Result,DiscLvl1,DiscLvl2,DiscLvl3,DiscLvl4,DiscLvl5
      from CalcPercent(:ITEMDISCPC, :UNITPRICE) into :ITEMDISC,:DiscLvl1,:DiscLvl2,:DiscLvl3,:DiscLvl4,:DiscLvl5;
    ITEMDISC  = cast(INVQTY as double precision) * cast(ITEMDISC as double precision);
    DiscLvl1  = cast(INVQTY as double precision) * cast(DiscLvl1 as double precision);
    DiscLvl2  = cast(INVQTY as double precision) * cast(DiscLvl2 as double precision);
    DiscLvl3  = cast(INVQTY as double precision) * cast(DiscLvl3 as double precision);
    DiscLvl4  = cast(INVQTY as double precision) * cast(DiscLvl4 as double precision);
    DiscLvl5  = cast(INVQTY as double precision) * cast(DiscLvl5 as double precision);
    EXTAMOUNT = (cast(INVQTY as double precision) * cast(UNITPRICE as double precision)) - ITEMDISC;
    select INVOICENO, INVOICEDATE, DESCRIPTION, CUSTOMERID, SALESMANID from ARINV where ARINVOICEID=:FID
      into :INVOICENO, :INVOICEDATE, :INVOICEDESCRIPTION, :PERSONID, :SALESMANID;
    INVOICETYPE = 0;
    INVOICEID = FID;
    SALESINVOICEID = FID;
    select max(d.PAYMENTID) from arinvpmt d inner join ARPMT m on m.PaymentID=d.PaymentID
      where m.FiscalPmt=0 and d.ARINVOICEID=:FID into :LASTPAYMENTID;
    if (LASTPAYMENTID is null) then
      LASTPAYMENTID = -1;
    select SalesQty, SalesAmount, COGSAmount from Get_SalesItemARINV(:ITEMNO,:FID, :SEQ)
           into :SALESQTY, :SALESAMOUNT, :COGSAMOUNT;
    GROSSPROFIT = SALESAMOUNT - COGSAMOUNT;
    GROSSPROFITPERCENT = 0;
    if (SALESAMOUNT <> 0) then
      GROSSPROFITPERCENT = (cast(GROSSPROFIT as double Precision)/cast(SALESAMOUNT as double precision)) * 100;
    suspend;
  end
  for select D.ARRefundID, D.Seq, S.ARINVOICEID,
    D.ITEMRESERVED1, D.ITEMRESERVED2, D.ITEMRESERVED3, D.ITEMRESERVED4, D.ITEMRESERVED5,
    D.ITEMRESERVED6, D.ITEMRESERVED7, D.ITEMRESERVED8, D.ITEMRESERVED9, D.ITEMRESERVED10, D.WAREHOUSEID,
    D.Quantity, D.DEPTID, D.PROJECTID, D.BRUTTOUNITPRICE, D.ITEMUNIT, D.TAXCODES, D.ITEMDISCPC, D.QTYCONTROL, D.ITEMOVDESC
    from ARREFDET D inner join ARREFUND M on M.ARRefundID=D.ARRefundID
    inner join ARINV S on S.ARINVOICEID=M.ARINVOICEID and S.DeliveryOrder=0
    where D.ITEMNO=:ITEMNO and M.InvoiceDate between :FDate and :TDate --and GroupSeq+0 is null
      into :FID, :SEQ, :FSIID, :ITEMRESERVED1, :ITEMRESERVED2, :ITEMRESERVED3, :ITEMRESERVED4, :ITEMRESERVED5,
    :ITEMRESERVED6, :ITEMRESERVED7, :ITEMRESERVED8, :ITEMRESERVED9, :ITEMRESERVED10, :WAREHOUSEID,
    :INVQTY, :DEPTID, :PROJECTID, :UNITPRICE, :ITEMUNIT, :TAXCODES, :ITEMDISCPC, :QTYCONTROL, :ITEMOVDESC do begin
    select Result,DiscLvl1,DiscLvl2,DiscLvl3,DiscLvl4,DiscLvl5
      from CalcPercent(:ITEMDISCPC, :UNITPRICE) into :ITEMDISC,:DiscLvl1,:DiscLvl2,:DiscLvl3,:DiscLvl4,:DiscLvl5;
    ITEMDISC  = - cast(INVQTY as double precision) * cast(ITEMDISC as double precision);
    DiscLvl1  = - cast(INVQTY as double precision) * cast(DiscLvl1 as double precision);
    DiscLvl2  = - cast(INVQTY as double precision) * cast(DiscLvl2 as double precision);
    DiscLvl3  = - cast(INVQTY as double precision) * cast(DiscLvl3 as double precision);
    DiscLvl4  = - cast(INVQTY as double precision) * cast(DiscLvl4 as double precision);
    DiscLvl5  = - cast(INVQTY as double precision) * cast(DiscLvl5 as double precision);
    EXTAMOUNT = (cast(INVQTY as double precision) * cast(UNITPRICE as double precision)) + ITEMDISC;
    select INVOICENO, INVOICEDATE, DESCRIPTION, CUSTOMERID, SALESMANID from ARREFUND R where ARREFUNDID=:FID
      into :INVOICENO, :INVOICEDATE, :INVOICEDESCRIPTION, :PERSONID, :SALESMANID;
    INVOICETYPE = 1;
    INVOICEID = FID;
    SALESINVOICEID = FSIID;
    LASTPAYMENTID = -1;
    select SalesQty, SalesAmount, COGSAmount from Get_SalesItemARRefund(:ITEMNO,:FID, :SEQ)
           into :SALESQTY, :SALESAMOUNT, :COGSAMOUNT;
    GROSSPROFIT = SALESAMOUNT - COGSAMOUNT;
    GROSSPROFITPERCENT = 0;
    if (SALESAMOUNT <> 0) then
      GROSSPROFITPERCENT = (cast(GROSSPROFIT as double Precision)/cast(SALESAMOUNT as double precision)) * 100;
    suspend;
  end
end
```

How can I remove the parameters to see all data as it works for View? (I am using Upscene Database Workbench 5 for database management)

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. If you want to remove the parameters, you will need to recreate the stored procedure without those parameters. If you're asking as to rewrite your stored procedure. That is too broad: we're not a code writing service.

Comment: Also note, that the code as shown only shows the body of the procedure, you're missing the crucial header of the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

One way I understand your question is than you want the procedure to NOT have your parameters into account.

You can send NULL parameters and do something like this inside ther procedure:
**where (FIELD = :PARAM) or (:PARAM IS NULL)**

```
/*From the first SELECT statement in your example */
select d.arinvoiceid, d.seq, d.itemreserved1, d.itemreserved2, ...
from arinvdet d
inner join arinv m on m.arinvoiceid = d.arinvoiceid
where
((d.itemno = :itemno) or (:itemno is null)) and
m.deliveryorder = 0 and
((invoicedate between :fdate and :tdate) or (:fdate is null) or (:tdate is null))
into ...
```